# Algorithm to merge the list of numbers to lower than and closest to the upper-bound number

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a upper-bound and a set of numbers, how to group the numbers to make the sum of the numbers closest to but NOT beyond the upper-bound?

**Example:**

`upper-bound = 10` and `numbers = {4, 4, 9, 3, 1, 7}`. The output can be either

1. `{4, 4, 1}, {9}, {3, 7}`
2. `{4, 4}, {9, 1}, {3, 7}`

Do I have to use a constraint solver? Or can the answer be simply obtained by Java code?

Comment: This is called the "bin packing" problem; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: @kaya3, you are totally right. Please post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), but phrased in a different way. The bin packing problem asks for how to fit the numbers within "bins" of a given capacity, minimising the number of bins used. Your problem asks for how to fit the numbers within bins, minimising the space "left over" in the bins.

The total space "left over" is related to the number of bins by a simple formula:

> Space left = (bins used) * (bin capacity) - (sum of input numbers)

Since the bin capacity and the sum of the input numbers are both determined by the inputs, the only variable which can be controlled on the right hand side is the number of bins used; it's clear that the space left over is minimised when the number of bins is minimised, so therefore the problems are equivalent.

The bin packing problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), so your choice of algorithm will depend on whether you need an exact answer, or if "good enough" is good enough. For exact answers, some kind of [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_search) is about as good as you can do. (If you use a [constraint solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming), it is probably doing something like a backtracking search.) Otherwise, there are well-studied [heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Analysis_of_approximate_algorithms) which guarantee solutions using a number of bins within a constant factor of the true optimum; some of these heuristics give better results than others, but may be more complicated to implement or take longer to run.